# VBA function to get windows user name

Tags: windows, vba, function, ms-access, authentication

My **MSAccess** database is located on a shared network folder;
This function works perfectly… but only for me – the database owner
For my colleague’s I get the error #name

Any ideas?

Found this function here!

```
Function UserNameWindows() As String
    UserNameWindows = VBA.Environ("USERNAME") & "@" & VBA.Environ("USERDOMAIN")
End Function
```

Comment: You should really have a separate front end database locally, on each users machine.Split your database -have a read here for just some of the reasons http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-plus-reasons-to-split-an-access-database/

Comment: I am very inexpedient with VBA.
So I split the database in the network folder and then I copy the front end to every workstation?

Comment: After reading 10 reasons to split… I finally understand… Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes - in simplest terms. Please take a backup copy before you do anything at all. You basically need to split out your data tables from your forms/queries and reports. Please read up carefully and backup before making wholesale changes.

Comment: It is already working. Thank you very much!